# C# get uri arguments

Tags: c#, url

http://localhost/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportServer?/Report+Project1&rs:Command=ListChildren

I would like get parts of url with report folder (Report Project1).
I tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments` but this return array with this items: "\", "ReportServer", "Reserved.ReportServer"

How I get parts with Report Project1?

Comment: This are query string paramaters ... Try this `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`

Comment: Thanks, but in QueryString is array AllKeys which contains 2 items: null and rs:Command, Report Project 1 isnt in this array

Comment: than you Need to build your url correctly which would be: ...ReportServer?/&Report=Project1&rs=ListChildren
or what is rs supposed to be.
than Access it via  ctx.Request.Params.Get("rs") or ("Report") or via QueryString

Comment: Or try removing the `/` after your `?`. this could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct solution:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get(0)
```

Comment: but be aware that the parameter has to be on first place ever

Comment: Yes, this url is in Reporting Server, it will not change

Comment: well then that fits :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the query in this request aren't standard i.e. the first parameter doesn't have a variable name only the folder path, you can't get the URI query param in a reliable way. The following code will provide the functionality you want, but perhaps using a simple String.split() looking for the regex of folder would be more reliable.

```
Uri temp = new Uri("http://localhost/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportServer?/Report+Project1&rs:Command=ListChildren");
string query = temp.Query;
var folder = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get(null);
```

Where the null value is in the Get method, you should really provide the variable name, in your example putting `rs:Command` there would return the value of that param.